# View not updating when assigning null property to object in Angular using 'rxjs/observable/zip'

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-ng-if

I'm having a problem with with my view not being updated once my component has updated a local property / variable.

In my component code I create a '`newAlbum`' property and originally assign it to null. Later when calling a method in my component called `openCreateForm` I wish to assign values to my 'newAlbum' property and then wish to update my view using a simple `*ngIf`

This is typescript code in my component...

```
newAlbum: { title: string, editableImageList: EditableImage[], description: string, fromDate: string} = null;

constructor(private store: Store<any>,
                private fileService: FileService) {
    // more stuff here that isn't important
    }


openCreateForm(fileList: File[]) {
    const editableImageObservableList = _.map(fileList, (file) => {
        return this.fileService.imageFileToDataUrl(file)
            .map((dataUrl) => {
                return new EditableImage(null, dataUrl);
            });
    });
    zip(...editableImageObservableList).subscribe((editableImageList: EditableImage[]) => {
        this.newAlbum = {
            title: 'My new album',
            editableImageList,
            description: null,
            fromDate: String(moment().year())
        };
    });
}
```

and this is the HTML in my component template (in an external file)

```
<div class="album__create" *ngIf="newAlbum">
    This content should be shown...
</div>
```

When debugging in Chrome Dev Tools and firing the `openCreateForm` method with the correct arguments the `this.newAlbum` is correctly assigned the correct properties and is no longer null... however my view doesn't get updated. Should I toggle between some DIVs on my interface the `*ngIf="newAlbum"` works correctly when returning or switching tabs in my view. Can anyway give me an idea on why the update isn't being fired or what I could do to force the update? Many thanks

If any of the above doesn't make sense please state so and I will reword the question... many thanks again.

Comment: When adding this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); after the new assignment to `this.album` works but it feels like a hack!

Comment: It seems like the change happens outside Angular. What `imageFileToDataUrl` or `EditableImage` do? Also how do you call `openCreateForm`?

Comment: `openCreateForm` is called when selected files from a `input type=file` is processed them emitted. `imageFileToDataUrl` converts the selected files to an observabes of dataUrls. EditableImage is a class / type that provides getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

`newAlbum` is of type `Any` as it is an object literal. Rather than relying on duck-typing to ensure that your new version of the object is picked up by change detection, why not create an interface for it.

```
interface Album{
     title: string; 
     editableImageList: EditableImage[]; 
     description: string; 
     fromDate: string
}
```

then

```
newAlbum: Album;
```

and in your subscription:

```
this.newAlbum = <Album>{
   title: 'My new album',
   editableImageList,
   description: null,
   fromDate: String(moment().year())
};
```

This may help with change-detection tracking the property, as it is of a well-known type

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to make any difference... it's as if the `zip(...editableImageObservableList).subscribe` doesn't trigger the change detection in Angular?

Comment: Tried to reproduce the problem in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8TQucXWMutBaLm7eqwyo), but everything works fine